# Is there any way to prevent chrome's password manager to save the password only for a specific web page?

Tags: oracle, google-chrome, security, passwords

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible for Chrome or any web browser to not to ask for saving password only for a specific web page?
(for example only if I log into Oracle BI or Oracle 12c admin page, I do not want a scenerio where user can save it later and may be exploited)

Answer (score 0):

I did this for not storing password in browser.

```
<input type="text" name="password" autocomplete="off" readonly 
onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" >
```

you can do same for username or email that you are using with passwords.